# How to increase no. of nfsd threads in WD my cloud (nfs server)? for better performance

Tags: linux, nfs, performance, optimization

There are only 8 default nfsd threads available in WD my cloud, this no. is not sufficient for my requirement. I want to increase default nfsd threads to 20 threads. For this I first connected with the wd my cloud through ssh. Found on internet that need's to edit RPCNFSDCOUNT parameter in /etc/sysconfig/nfs file, but sysconfig folder is not there. Linux version is 3.10.39 armv7l. How can I increase no. nfsd thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Linux `nfsd(8)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nfsd.8.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    /usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd [options] nproc
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    nproc  specify the number of NFS server threads. By default, eight
>           threads are started. However, for optimum performance several
>           threads should be used. The actual figure depends on the
>           number of and the work load created by the NFS clients, but a
>           useful starting point is eight threads. Effects of modifying
>           that number can be checked using the nfsstat(8) program.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **CONFIGURATION FILE**
>
> ```
>    Many of the options that can be set on the command line can also be
>    controlled through values set in the [nfsd] section of the
>    /etc/nfs.conf configuration file.  Values recognized include:
>
>    threads
>           The number of threads to start.
>
>    ...
> ```

I'd venture your best option is to modify `/etc/nfs.conf`, assuming that's how your Linux installation is configured.

Comment: This helps to modify nsfd thread count without restarting the service